# Typescript infers object key to number instead of string

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use a stringly keyed object literal and create a type that is `"monkey"` named `Testing`. However, it infers `string | number`:

[image: monkeying around, repro]

How do I correct it?

As a counter-example to the comment, creating an Enum-indexed object looks correct:

[image: enum objects]

Comment: String index signature key types [include `number` since TS2.9](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types).  What do you see as needing correction?

Comment: All keys of the object are `string`, never `number`, and specifically, I expect the `Testing` type to be aliased to `"testing"` (a string value as a type). Or as seen from the other side around: why doesn't `[k: number]` signatures produce `string | number` `Testing` types? And why doesn't enum?

Comment: `number` indexes aren't really `number`... since in JavaScript all index access is coerced to `string` values first... so `a[1]` is the same as `a["1"]`.  In TypeScript, a `number` index is *really* is a special subset of a `string` index.  Read [this documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).  If this makes sense to you I can turn it into an answer.

Comment: Also, please avoid posting images of code, as described in [the guidelines for how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type annotation `{ [k: string]: Record<string, any> }` throws away the actual key(-types) of the object by generalising all of them to `string` or `number`.

That string-keys are inferred to `string | number` is probably a quirk in how TypeScript deals with [string indexers](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types)

Comment: "That string-keys are inferred to `string | number `is probably a bug." No, it is intended behavior, introduced in TS2.9: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types "If `X` contains a string index signature, `keyof X` is a union of `string`, `number`, and the literal types representing symbol-like properties"